# Optimize sql query by indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

Query:

```
SELECT text, date FROM table WHERE TO_CHAR (date, 'YYYY') = '2014'
```

Does this query use index 'date'?

Comment: Prefix the query with explain and it will show that it doesn't. Between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31' is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

No. MySQL of today don't use indexes on computed columns.

As Tony Hopkinson said, it would be better to rewrite your query as

```
SELECT 
    text, date 
FROM `table` 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

I'm sure your table name `table` is meant as example. But an identifier that is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) must be quoted.